# Sharepoint Intranet templates needed

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I need template for my intranet site. It must show company links,News and a good ui for that. Can anyone help me getting these atleast a free one for now so that i can show this to my manager and get it approved. Can anyone please help me.
It is Sharepoint server 2016 not online or O365

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used any of these, but just something I came across by throwing "*sharepoint 2016 free templates*" to Google.

Templates listed ad Collab365 seem to have a nice variety of choices. These can be found here: https://directory.collab365.community/office365-sharepoint/best-sharepoint-intranet-templates/.

Note that it's your responsibility to understand what you would install when taking a 3rd party template into use. Templates also have several types so some are maybe suitable for your typical newspaper-style, some for enterprise intranets, some for public websites, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to find the template that will match your requirements . So it's recommended to build your own template based on your business requirements that require .

However , i find some reference below :

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/4d627d76-4876-4fb3-9997-5f16d13dfed5/free-site-templates-for-sharepoint-2013-office-365?forum=sharepointgeneral

http://www.spsdemo.com/websites/Pages/default.aspx